# 2010 Focus OEM satellite radio

Tags: electrical, ford, focus, electronics

I have a 2010 Ford Focus S. I noticed a Sirius radio button and phone button. The Sirius button will trigger a “no satellite radio” message, and the phone button triggers “no phone”. After looking into this, I found that I don’t have the required module for these functions. Is it possible to install the OEM module even though it’s not an option on my trim level? If so, is it plug and play or do I need to program it?

Answer (score 1):

You may be lucky and have the wiring already installed - decoding the vin number may tell you that, if yes then fit the modules and see if they get recognised.

This is one site and ford do one themselves but I don’t have it on my smartphone : https://www.vindecoderz.com/EN/Ford

Edit: now on computer here is the Ford link (that I have used, not sure if it is country specific) :
[Ford Etis site](https://www.etis.ford.com/vehicleRegSelector.do;jsessionid=RPUrE07NEfizVg3ZBeXyYu2IU6P6qsWrL8X7vtR0.fcvas1901l)